# how to sort a grid by using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I Need to sort a list of elements , can i do that by using selenium web driver if it is  possible means  give me some sample example with web driver code are any reference link to go through

Comment: I have to sort able  elements by using mouse , is it possible in selenium

Comment: If thats your question..then yes we can do it :)

Comment: sorry I am beginer ,so  can u please  give me a sample code  wth example